# Highchart clickable link in tooptip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to create a highchart with each project has own url(clickable),  for each data inside tooltip.

```
series: [{
  tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function() {
      var string = '';
      Highcharts.each(toolTip[this.series.data.indexOf(this)], function(p) {
        string += '<a href="'+ urls +'">' + p + '</a><br>'
      });
      return string + "<br />";
    }
  },
  type: 'spline',
  data: data
}]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SeCAB/262/)

How can I set each project get own url from `urls`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated series used `urls[indexs][j]` instead of `urls`

```
 series: [{
  tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function() {
      var string = '';
      var indexs = this.series.data.indexOf(this);
      Highcharts.each(toolTip[this.series.data.indexOf(this)], function(p, j) {
        string += '<a href="' + urls[indexs][j] + '">' + p + '</a><br>'
      });
      return string + "<br />";
    }
  },
  type: 'spline',
  data: data
}]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr6md3wo/) demo